# Read data from XML in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, xml

I am having an issue in reading data from an XML column in the database. I need to read the data where the screenshot below says

```
<LicenseSeats>47</LicenseSeats>
```

[image]

This is the code I am using, but when I run it, it returns NULL.

```
SELECT                      
    T.C.value('LicenseSeats[47]', 'int') AS LicenseSeats
FROM
    table_license.Licenses
CROSS APPLY                 
    LicenseFile.nodes('//LicenseSeats') AS T(C)
```

hello guys here is the full xml file

```
<company:License xmlns:company="urn://schemas.company.com/licensing/license/v1">
  <LicenseKey>*****</LicenseKey>
  <LicenseModel>Concurrent</LicenseModel>
  <LicenseSeats>47</LicenseSeats>
  <HardwareKey>*****</HardwareKey>
  <GeneratedOn>2017-12-14T19:27:35.9051262Z</GeneratedOn>
  <ExpiresOn>2020-10-01T04:00:00Z</ExpiresOn>
  <ProductId>83e19906-fc53-4187-a258-ae6993873a01</ProductId>
  <ProductName>App WMS System</ProductName>
  <CustomerName>Company</CustomerName>
  <Features>
    <Feature id="*******" name="3PL Management" />
    <Feature id="*******" name="Manufacturing" />
    <Feature id="*******" name="Yard Management" />
  </Features>
  <Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
    <SignedInfo>
      <CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315" />
      <SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1" />
      <Reference URI="">
        <Transforms>
          <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature" />
        </Transforms>
        <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1" />
        <DigestValue>*******=</DigestValue>
      </Reference>
    </SignedInfo>
    <SignatureValue>******</SignatureValue>
  </Signature>
</company:License>
```

Comment: The `<company:License>` node **obviously** is in a XML namespace (which is *not shown* in your screenshot) - so you need to **include** that namespace in your querying....

Comment: This still **cannot** be the full XML - the `company:` XML namespace is **not** defined anywhere in what you posted....

Comment: I added new change to the xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
WITH XMLNAMESPACES('urn://schemas.company.com/licensing/license/v1' AS cpy)
SELECT
    LicenseSeats = XC.value('(LicenseSeats)[1]', 'int')
FROM
    table_license.Licenses
CROSS APPLY                 
    LicenseFile.nodes('/cpy:License') AS XT(XC)
```

This should get you the value `47` from the `<LicenseSeats>` element of your XML

Comment: Thanks man that actually worked. I was able to get the result I needed I just had to change the int to nvarchar because the value is set as nvarchar not int. but that query did the trick thanks again.

Comment: @AndresBryan29: if this answer helped you solve your problem, then please [**accept this answer**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5234/153998). This will show your appreciation for the people who *spent their own time to help you*.

Answer (score 1):

There's a namespace in your XML, you need to let SQL Server know about that.

Not tested, as you've provided an image rather than actual xml, but:

```
WITH XMLNAMESPACES (DEFAULT 'urn://schema.company.com/licensing/licence/v1')
SELECT T.C.value('LicenseSeats[47]', 'int') AS LicenseSeats
FROM table_license.Licenses
     CROSS APPLY LicenseFile.nodes('//LicenseSeats') AS T(C);
```

If that doesn't work (and it's not because I've missed typed the uri),please provide consumable sample data.

Thanks.

Comment: No, the `xmlns:datex` is not the default namespace... The visible XML is not  valid, as the root node lives within the `company` namespace, which is not declared...  A lot is missing here...

Comment: Indeed, you're right. I'm not, however, entertaining writing out the OPs xml myself though, so *hopefully* they're edit with some usable data.

Comment: guys I added the full xml in the first post, please review it your first solution didn't work